# How to get active records for each date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below:

```
ID  FID MDate       Active
--------------------------
1   1   2009-05-25  1
1   2   2009-05-25  1
1   1   2010-02-04  0
1   3   2010-02-04  1
1   1   2009-04-01  0
1   1   2009-03-01  1
```

How to get active `FId` for each date?

I was trying like below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ID, MDate,
    STUFF ((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST(FID AS VARCHAR) 
            FROM 
                (SELECT ID, MDate, FID 
                 FROM Table1 
                 WHERE IsActive = 1) t
            WHERE t.MDate = a.MDate 
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') colb
FROM 
    (SELECT ID, MDate, FID 
     FROM Table1 
     WHERE IsActive = 1) a
```

Somehow, it is giving partial results. In last row of the result of above query FID 3 is getting selected, there should be two FIDs  `2, 3` as FID 2 is active since `2009-05-25` to till date.

I want output like below:

```
ID  MDate       FID
1   2009-03-01  1
1   2009-05-25  1,2
1   2010-02-04  2,3
```

How to get this in SQL?

Comment: please specify a size for the varchar. CAST (FID AS VARCHAR(10))

Comment: you can't because your new FID field needs to be as large as your number of rows

Comment: There is *no* active record for `2009-04-01`, so how is this result row `(1   '2009-04-01'  '2,3')` justified?

Comment: sorry for the typing mistake. i have updated question.

Comment: @Akki I have edited my answer, please, give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify names of fields correctly, and no need for that number of sub-query:

```
;WITH Table1 AS (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
(1, 1, '2009-05-25', 1),
(1, 2, '2009-05-25', 1),
(1, 1, '2010-02-04', 0),
(1, 3, '2010-02-04', 1),
(1, 1, '2009-04-01', 0),
(1, 1, '2009-03-01', 1))
AS t(ID, FID, ModifyDate, IsActive)
)

SELECT DISTINCT ID,
                ModifyDate,
                STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST(FID AS VARCHAR) 
                        FROM Table1 t
                        WHERE t.ModifyDate = a.ModifyDate
                        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') colb
FROM Table1 a
WHERE IsActive=1
```

Results:

```
ID          ModifyDate colb
----------- ---------- ----------
1           2009-03-01 1
1           2009-05-25 1,2
1           2010-02-04 1,3

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a CTE to filter out the active row first

```
; WITH
CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Table1
    WHERE   IsActive    = 1
)
SELECT  ID, ModifyDate,
    colb    = STUFF (   (   
                    SELECT  ',' + CAST(FID AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                    FROM    CTE x 
                    WHERE   x.ModifyDate = c.ModifyDate 
                    FOR XML PATH ('')
                ) , 1, 1, '')
FROM    CTE c
GROUP BY ID, ModifyDate
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. FID 2 is active on 2010-02-04 which is not getting selected here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct [ID],[MDate],STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(FID AS VARCHAR) FROM [dbo].[tableName] WHERE [MDate] = a.[MDate] and active =1 FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1 ,'') as FID
  FROM [dbo].[tableName] AS a
  WHERE  active = 1
  ORDER BY [MDate]
```

Sample Output as below:

```
ID  MDate       FID
1   2009-03-01  1
1   2009-05-25  1,2
1   2010-02-04  3
```

I think this is what you want.